# CSS menu align is not stable in different browsers

Tags: css, menu, alignment

Here is my page : http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/1905_YPA/index.php . I have a problem with CSS. The menu align changes if the site is opened in different browsers. I checked that from 3 different computers and the menu was not perfectly aligned. Secondly, when i minimize the menu doesn't align as well. What should I do ?

I used Stylizer to change the CSS code. Here is the code:

```
    *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
BODY
{
    margin-top: 220px;
    background: #000 url(images/button.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
H1, H2, H3
{
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
H2
{
    font: 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
H3
{
    font-size: large;
    color: #F00;
}
P, BLOCKQUOTE, UL, OL
{
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-align: inherit;
}
P
{
}
BLOCKQUOTE
{
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
}
UL
{
    /*[empty]margin-left:;*/
}
UL LI
{
}
OL
{
    /*[empty]margin-left:;*/
}
OL LI
{
}
A
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
A:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/*Boxed Style*/
.boxed
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.boxed .content
{
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
/*Post*/
.post
{
    /*[empty]margin:;*/
}
.post .title
{
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.post .story
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
/*Header*/
#header
{
    height: 61px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/*Header > Logo*/
#logo
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 19px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 6px 0 0;
}
#logo H1, #logo H2
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#logo H1
{
    float: left;
}
#logo H2
{
    float: right;
}
#logo A
{
}
/*Header > Menu*/
#menu
{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 27px;
}
#menu UL
{
    /*[empty]margin-left:;*/
    padding: 7px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu LI
{
    display: inline;
}
#menu A
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 2px 25px 0;
    background: url(#FFFFF) repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #014995;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #014995;
}
#menu A:hover
{
    background-image: url(images/13.jpg);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E5E5E5;
}
#menu .active A
{
    background-image: url(images/12.jpg);
}
/*Wrapper >Font*/
#fonts
{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
/*Centre Wrapper*/
#wrapper
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/*Content*/
#content
{
    width: 60px;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}


#login INPUT
{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #385B88;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#inputtext1, #inputtext2, #inputtext3
{
    color: #014995;
}
#inputsubmit1
{
    background: #385B88;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it doesn't look like the design is fluid or responsive at all, this is a pretty simple fix. Just add "margin-right: -10px;" to the style rule for #menu. This will shift the menu over to where it's supposed to start.

In other words:

```
#menu {
   margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: What is the "bat" ? 

I changed it a bit if you can see in the site. When i zoom in,out the button menu changes. The other part of the menu is good. So still a problem :(

Comment: The "bat" is just American slang (we have lots of slang related to baseball here). If you zoom in, yes, the bigger text will break the menu. You can make set the text to "font: 16px" (change the number to the font size you want). However, unless the site is supposed to work on mobile phones as well, I don't think it's too important.

Comment: I wrote the margin in the css code but still the same. The menu position is different from browser to browser and pc to pc :(